# How to split text from the Clipboard into a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, clipboard

I would like to split the text I'm copying from a website into a DataGridView control.
The text I'm copying, in particular, comes from Binance website and the format its the following:

[image]

My DataGridView control contains 9 Columns:
`Date`, `Pair`, `Type`, `Side`, `Average`, `Price`, `Executed`, `Amount`, `Total`.

Copying

> 03-17 10:55:03 DOGE/EUR Limit Buy 0.04816 0.04816 11,740.0 11,740.8 565.39840

I want to paste it into my DataGridView in order to fill the relative Columns, but, when I'm pasting it, just the cell of Date column is being filled. Is there a way to split the text?

Edit:
Binary representation of the Clipboard content:

[image]

```
30 33 2d 31 37 20 32 32 3a 35 37 3a 32 38 0d 0a
44 4f 47 45 2f 45 55 52 0d 0a 4c 69 6d 69 74 0d
0a 53 65 6c 6c 0d 0a 30 2e 30 34 38 37 38 0d 0a
30 2e 30 34 38 37 38 0d 0a 33 30 2c 35 32 36 2e
30 0d 0a 33 30 2c 35 32 36 2e 30 0d 0a 31 2c 34
38 39 2e 30 35 38 32 38 0d 0a 30 33 2d 31 37 20
31 33 3a 31 39 3a 33 39 0d 0a 44 4f 47 45 2f 45
55 52 0d 0a 4c 69 6d 69 74 0d 0a 42 75 79 0d 0a
30 2e 30 34 38 30 30 0d 0a 30 2e 30 34 38 30 30
0d 0a 31 2c 31 30 30 2e 38 0d 0a 31 2c 31 30 30
2e 38 0d 0a 35 32 2e 38 33 38 34 30 0d 0a 30 33
2d 31 37 20 31 30 3a 35 35 3a 30 33 0d 0a 44 4f
47 45 2f 45 55 52 0d 0a 4c 69 6d 69 74 0d 0a 42
75 79 0d 0a 30 2e 30 34 38 31 36 0d 0a 30 2e 30
34 38 31 36 0d 0a 31 31 2c 37 34 30 2e 38 0d 0a
31 31 2c 37 34 30 2e 38 0d 0a 35 36 35 2e 34 33
36 39 33 0d 0a 30 33 2d 31 37 20 31 30 3a 33 31
3a 35 33 0d 0a 44 4f 47 45 2f 45 55 52 0d 0a 4c
69 6d 69 74 0d 0a 42 75 79 0d 0a 30 2e 30 34 38
32 30 0d 0a 30 2e 30 34 38 32 30 0d 0a 31 31 2c
39 37 30 2e 33 0d 0a 31 31 2c 39 37 30 2e 33 0d
0a 35 37 36 2e 39 36 38 34 36
```

Edit2:
Second binary

```
30 33 2d 31 37 20 32 32 3a 35 37 3a 32 38 0d 0a
44 4f 47 45 2f 45 55 52 0d 0a 4c 69 6d 69 74 0d
0a 53 65 6c 6c 0d 0a 30 2e 30 34 38 37 38 0d 0a
30 2e 30 34 38 37 38 0d 0a 33 30 2c 35 32 36 2e
30 0d 0a 33 30 2c 35 32 36 2e 30 0d 0a 31 2c 34
38 39 2e 30 35 38 32 38
```

Comment: When you copy data from a *Table* in a HTML page, you can get each *Field* in the *Row* separated by `\r\n` (quite common) or even `\r\n\t` (`0D 0A` or `0D 0A 09` - `CR LF` or `CR LF TAB`). The *Rows* are usually (also) separated by `\r\n` So, you have to determine which format you receive and build a parser that can handle that specific format and have a Control in the UI that can store that exact number of Fields. Converting the DateTime Field is not a problem: if you have an input as `03-17 10:55:03`, then `dim dtm = Date.ParseExact("03-17 10:55:03", "MM-dd H:mm:ss", Nothing)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample Hex data posted here, all Fields in the data source, copied from a Web Table, are separated by `0x0D 0x0A` (`\r\n`, i.e. `ChrW(13) ChrW(10)`, i.e. `vbCrLf`).
So are the Rows.

To parse this format, you need to know how many Fields compose a Row, to determine when a Carriage Return+Line Feed defines the boundaries of a Field or a Row.
In the sample presented here, the data source is compose of `9` Fields, so I'm keeping this reference as the Format to consider.
Of course the simple parser can be adapted to a different format, in case it's needed.

After the source data has been copied to the Clipboard from a WebBrowser, we can retrieve the data as text using [Clipboard.GetText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.gettext).
Here, I'm trimming any `ChrW(13) ChrW(10) ChrW(32)` from the beginning and end of the text, in case some of these were added by mistake while selecting the HTML text.

The parser retrieves all parts from the text and checks whether the resulting array of strings is a multiple of `9`. If not, throws an exception (we cannot parse this format, it's assumed that a Row will contain `9` Fields).

The array of strings is then converted to an `Object()` array, containing all the values already converted to the destination Type. The array is the used as the source of a new Row of the DataTable - which is *attached* to a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) - used as the source of data for the DataGridView.
The DataTable also defines a Column that is used as an auto-incrementing index.

---

In the Form Constructor, the Data Source and the DataGridView are initialized calling the `InitializeDataSource()` and  `InitializeBinanceUI()` methods.
These method initialize the DataTable and the base Format of the DataGridView Columns, plus and event handler used to change the Color of the text one of the Columns.

**Note**: The DataGridView here is named `dgvBinance`. Add one in the Form designer and rename it like this.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Globalization

Private binanceSource As BindingSource = Nothing
Private binanceData As DataTable = Nothing

Public Class SomeForm
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ' [...]
        InitializeDataSource()
        InitializeBinanceUI()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeDataSource()
        binanceData = New DataTable("BinanceData")
        binanceData.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {
            .ColumnName = "Index",
            .AutoIncrement = True,
            .AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
            .AutoIncrementStep = 1
        })

        binanceData.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Pair", GetType(String))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Type", GetType(String))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Side", GetType(String))

        binanceData.Columns.Add("Average", GetType(Decimal))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Decimal))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Executed", GetType(Decimal))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Amount", GetType(Decimal))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Total", GetType(Decimal))
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeBinanceUI()
        AddHandler dgvBinance.CellFormatting, AddressOf dgvBinanceCellFormatting
        binanceSource = New BindingSource(binanceData, "")
        dgvBinance.DataSource = binanceSource
        dgvBinance.Columns("Date").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM-dd H:mm:ss"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Average").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N5"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Price").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N5"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Executed").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N1"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Amount").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N1"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Total").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N5"
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvBinanceCellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
        If e.Value Is Nothing OrElse dgvBinance.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name <> "Side" Then Return
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = If(e.Value.ToString().Equals("Buy"), Color.Green, Color.Red)
    End Sub
End Sub
```

When you need to paste new Rows into the Control, get the text from the Clipboard and call the parser, passing the text you got from the Clipboard and the DataTable used as DataSource.
The BindingSource that uses the DataTable as source will update the UI.

```
Dim sourceData = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)
Dim rowsAdded = BinanceParseCopyData(sourceData, binanceData)
```

**Parser**:

```
Private Function BinanceParseCopyData(input As String, dataSource As DataTable) As Integer
    Dim culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    input.Trim({ChrW(13), ChrW(10), ChrW(32)})

    Dim allData = input.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    If allData.Length Mod 9 <> 0 Then
        Throw New FormatException($"Unexpected Data Format. A Data Row must be composed of 9 Columns. Found {allData.Length}")
    End If

    Dim rowsCount As Integer = 0
    For pos As Integer = 0 To allData.Length - 1 Step 9
        Dim row As Object() = New Object(9) {}
        Array.Copy(allData, pos, row, 1, 9)
        ' row(0) remains null, since the Column at this index is used by 
        ' the DataTable for the automatic indexer (and expects null as value)
        row(1) = Date.ParseExact(row(1).ToString().Trim(), "MM-dd H:mm:ss", culture)
        row(2) = row(2).ToString().Trim()
        row(3) = row(3).ToString().Trim()
        row(4) = row(4).ToString().Trim()
        row(5) = Decimal.Parse(row(5).ToString().Trim(), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint Or NumberStyles.AllowThousands, culture)
        row(6) = Decimal.Parse(row(6).ToString().Trim(), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint Or NumberStyles.AllowThousands, culture)
        row(7) = Decimal.Parse(row(7).ToString().Trim(), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint Or NumberStyles.AllowThousands, culture)
        row(8) = Decimal.Parse(row(8).ToString().Trim(), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint Or NumberStyles.AllowThousands, culture)
        row(9) = Decimal.Parse(row(9).ToString().Trim(), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint Or NumberStyles.AllowThousands, culture)
        dataSource.Rows.Add(row)
        rowsCount += 1
    Next
    Return rowsCount
End Function
```

Graphic sample of the results:

[image: Binance Web Copy]

---

The Form and the DataGridView shown in the animation can be found in this PasteBin:
[Form class + Designer](https://pastebin.com/QxiHNYeQ)

The ContextMenuStrip is designed using a custom [ToolStripProfessionalRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.-ctor) which uses a custom [ProfessionalColorTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable) attached to a *replaceable* Color definition class (can be replaced with another at run-time or design-time).
All the object used for the customization are posted here:
[Change space between Image and Text in ContextMenuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130479/7444103)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
Private _yourCopiedRows As String
Private _temporaryArray() As String

_yourCopiedRows = "the value from your clipboard"

_temporaryArray = Split(_yourCopiedRows, " ")
```

Then paste them to DataGridView's columns one by one

```
DataGridView.Rows.Add(_temporaryArray(0).ToString, _temporaryArray(1).ToString, etc..)
```

But I think its better to write your own paste method from your clipboard up to your DataGridView.

[Strings.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Hi, i want to implement a solution that allows me to paste in the first column cell and split automatically  in the others.

Comment: Then look for KeyPress or KeyDown event in case you're pasting using `CTRL + V`, then use that split sample I gave to you for setting values to each columns.