# How to serialize and deserialize JSON file into a DataTable to fill a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable, datagridview, json.net

I want to save the values of a DataTable which is attached to a BindingSource used as the source of data for the DataGridView. The code I'm using comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66696343/14538918)

I managed to serialize the DataTable into a JSON and save it into a text file with the following code in the `Form.FormClosing` event:

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Mattia\Desktop\json.txt"   

Private Sub form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(binanceData, Formatting.Indented)
    File.WriteAllText(path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented))
End Sub
```

Unfortunately the JSON string I'm getting into `file.txt` looks like this:

> "[\r\n  {\r\n    "Index": 1,\r\n    "Date": "2021-03-18T08:44:43",\r\n    "Pair": "DOGE/EUR",\r\n    "Type": "Limit",\r\n    "Side": "Buy",\r\n    "Average": 0.04815,\r\n    "Price": 0.04815,\r\n    "Executed": 30526.0,\r\n    "Amount": 30526.0,\r\n    "Total": 1469.82690\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    "Index": 2,\r\n    "Date": "2021-03-18T08:44:43",\r\n    "Pair": "DOGE/EUR",\r\n    "Type": "Limit",\r\n    "Side": "Buy",\r\n    "Average": 0.04815,\r\n    "Price": 0.04815,\r\n    "Executed": 30526.0,\r\n    "Amount": 30526.0,\r\n    "Total": 1469.82690\r\n  }\r\n]"

which is not a valid JSON format.
Because of this, the JSON deserialization to DataTable doesn't not work.

In `Form.Load` I use this code to deserialize the JSON:

```
binanceData = TryCast(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(path, (GetType(DataTable))), DataTable)
```

This causes an exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks

Edit:
The JSON format I'm getting in the text file now is:

```
[
  {
    "Index": 1,
    "Date": "2021-03-18T08:44:43",
    "Pair": "DOGE/EUR",
    "Type": "Limit",
    "Side": "Buy",
    "Average": 0.04815,
    "Price": 0.04815,
    "Executed": 30526.0,
    "Amount": 30526.0,
    "Total": 1469.82690
  }
]
```

Comment: Think your problem is your are trying to deserialize the file path, not the file content.  You probably need to read the contents of that file into a string, then deserialize that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need serialize the data pasted into a DataGridView to a JSON file.
- The source of data of your DataGridView is a DataTable.

The Json.Net serializer can handle this nicely, the deserializer a little less, it may *misinterpret* some of the Types, in this case a floating point value is read as `Double` instead of `Decimal`. An Integer is usually treated as a `Long` instead.

Not much of a problem, we can change the auto-indexer of the DataTable to Type `Long` and use [JsonSerializerSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) to specify that floating point values need to be handled as `Decimal`, setting `FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal`.

What remains to do is to *instruct* the code not to destroy the current DataTable object when the JSON file doesn't contain any data.
We should also check whether the JSON file exists in the first place.

Better save the JSON file to a Path where we have write access for sure: this can be the Path returned by [Application.CommonAppDataPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.commonappdatapath), since you have a WinForms app.
This Path points to the Folder reserved for your application in:

```
[Drive]:\ProgramData\[ApplicationName]\[ApplicationVersion]
```

You can always read from and write to this path.

Let's add a Field that specifies the JSON file path.

```
Private jsonPath As String = Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, "BinanceData.json")
```

When the Form is initialized, you're running a procedure that creates the DataTable object and defines the Type of its Columns.
If the JSON file exists and it contains data, we deserialize the JSON to a DataTable and set it to the DataTable Field used to bind the DataGridView Control, linked to a BindingSource.
Otherwise, we set an empty DataTable that just contains the schema.

Requires Json.Net 12.0.3+

The complete procedure is described here:
[How to split text from the Clipboard into a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66688334/7444103)

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class SomeForm

    Private binanceSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private binanceData As DataTable = Nothing
    Private jsonPath As String = 
        Path.Combine(Application.CommonAppDataPath, "BinanceData.json")

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ' [...]
        InitializeDataSource()
        InitializeBinanceUI()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeDataSource()
        If File.Exists(jsonPath) Then
            Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings() With {
                .FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal
            }
            Dim json = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath)
            Dim dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json, settings)
            If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Columns.Count > 0 Then
                dt.Columns("Index").AutoIncrement = True
                dt.Columns("Index").AutoIncrementSeed = CType(dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("Index"), Long) + 1
                dt.Columns("Index").AutoIncrementStep = 1
                binanceData = dt
                Return
            End If
        End If

        binanceData = New DataTable("BinanceData")
        binanceData.Columns.Add(New DataColumn() With {
            .DataType = GetType(Long),
            .ColumnName = "Index",
            .AutoIncrement = True,
            .AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
            .AutoIncrementStep = 1
        })

        binanceData.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Pair", GetType(String))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Type", GetType(String))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Side", GetType(String))

        binanceData.Columns.Add("Average", GetType(Decimal))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Decimal))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Executed", GetType(Decimal))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Amount", GetType(Decimal))
        binanceData.Columns.Add("Total", GetType(Decimal))
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeBinanceUI()
        AddHandler dgvBinance.CellFormatting, AddressOf dgvBinanceCellFormatting
        binanceSource = New BindingSource(binanceData, "")
        dgvBinance.DataSource = binanceSource
        dgvBinance.Columns("Date").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM-dd H:mm:ss"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Average").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N5"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Price").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N5"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Executed").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N1"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Amount").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N1"
        dgvBinance.Columns("Total").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N5"
    End Sub
End Sub
```

When the Form closes, we save the data to the JSON file, serializing the DataTable content, calling the `SerializeBinanceDataTable()` method from the `FormClosing` handler. Of course you can call this method, if required, in any other case.

```
Private Sub SomeForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    SerializeBinanceDataTable()
End Sub

Private Sub SerializeBinanceDataTable()
    Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(binanceData, Formatting.Indented)
    File.WriteAllText(jsonPath, json)
End Sub
```