# Area for check mark in WinForms ContextMenuStrip is narrow on high dpi

Tags: .net, winforms, drop-down-menu, contextmenustrip, highdpi

We have a WinForms app for .NET Framework 4.7.2. The main form contains a toolbar based on the [ToolStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip) component. One of the buttons displays a drop-down menu based on the [ContextMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip) component. The whole construction looks like this:

```C#
private ToolStrip MainToolStrip;
private ToolStripDropDownButton TextSizeButton;
private ContextMenuStrip TextSizeMenu;

MainToolStrip = new ToolStrip();
TextSizeButton = new ToolStripDropDownButton();
TextSizeMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();

MainToolStrip.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] {..., TextSizeButton, ...});

TextSizeButton.DropDown = TextSizeMenu;
```

High dpi support is enabled in the app using the standard `<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>` element in the app config file (according to [this Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)).

This drop-down menu looks good on a normal 96dpi screen, but the picture is not so good on a high-res screen because the width of the gray area for check mark is not enough:

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any further incompatibilities and side effects related to the standard implementation of check marks in `ContextMenuStrip`, we decided to simply use our own image as the check mark:

[image] [image]

It looks even cooler than the default one because the default implementation draws the selection rectangle around the check mark (why?!):

[image]

The core part of code that switches the check state is the following:

```
private Bitmap ImageCheck = CreateToolButtonResBitmap("check.png");
private Bitmap ImageEmpty = CreateToolButtonResBitmap("10tec-empty.png");

private void SetMenuItemChecked(ToolStripMenuItem item, bool check)
{
    if (check)
        item.Image = ImageCheck;
    else
        item.Image = ImageEmpty;
}
```

And we also remove the unneeded gray area at the left of `ContextMenuStrip` for better effect:

```
internal class DropDownToolbarRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderImageMargin(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

private static DropDownToolbarRenderer fDropDownToolbarRenderer = new DropDownToolbarRenderer();

TextSizeMenu.Renderer = fDropDownToolbarRenderer;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to specifically set the width of the image/check margin. When I looked at the `.NET` source code, it seemed like there were two options. Option 1) One of the `ToolStripMenuItem` objects has to have a dummy image (e.g. height = 1 pixel, width = desired margin width), so that the image would force the margin to be the desired width. The disadvantage of this approach is that if the `Font` size is changed then it requires generating a new dummy image. Option 2) use reflection to access certain `private` fields, not ideal, but this was the easier of the two options. Here is some code for option #2:

```
//</summary>Keeps the checkboxes square dimensions. The image margin is at least the height, or the width of the widest ToolStripItem image.</summary>
private class ContextMenuStrip2 : ContextMenuStrip {
    private static FieldInfo fieldScaledDefaultImageMarginWidth = null;
    private static FieldInfo fieldScaledDefaultImageSize = null;
    private static bool scaledFields = false;
    static ContextMenuStrip2() {
        try {
            Type ty = typeof(ToolStripDropDownMenu);
            fieldScaledDefaultImageMarginWidth = ty.GetField("scaledDefaultImageMarginWidth", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            fieldScaledDefaultImageSize = ty.GetField("scaledDefaultImageSize", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            scaledFields = (fieldScaledDefaultImageMarginWidth != null && fieldScaledDefaultImageSize != null);
        } catch {}
    }


    private int currentImageMarginWidth = -1;
    private bool isAdjusting = false;

    public ContextMenuStrip2() : base() {
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e) {
        base.OnLayout(e);

        if (!isAdjusting && scaledFields && this.Items.Count > 0) {
            int wMax = 0;
            foreach (ToolStripItem i in Items) {
                int h = i.Height + 3;
                if (h > wMax)
                    wMax = h;
                if (i.Image != null) {
                    int w = i.Image.Width + 4;
                    if (w > wMax)
                        wMax = w;
                }
            }

            if (wMax != currentImageMarginWidth) {
                currentImageMarginWidth = wMax;
                fieldScaledDefaultImageMarginWidth.SetValue(this, wMax);
                fieldScaledDefaultImageSize.SetValue(this, new Size(1000, 0)); // must do this to cancel out extraImageWidth in CalculateInternalLayoutMetrics()
                isAdjusting = true;
                ResumeLayout(true);
                isAdjusting = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can override [ToolStripProfessionalRenderer.OnRenderImageMargin()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.onrenderimagemargin) and [OnRenderItemImage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.onrenderitemimage) or [OnRenderItemCheck()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.onrenderitemcheck) -- Or make the app scale on Dpi instead of Font. Or both.

Comment: @jimi That doesn't change the width of the image margin.

Comment: You can render the Image or check symbol where you want. The menu items can also be moved, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130479/7444103). You can render the entire menu as you please.

Comment: There's also the `Toolstrip.DisableHighDpiImprovements` setting, in app.config. It's not clear what options the OP has chosen, or modified.

Comment: When you override `OnRenderImageMargin()`, you can create a new `ToolStripRenderEventArgs` object (it's not sealed), inflate the `e.AffectedBounds` rectangle, pass the new Rectangle to the `ToolStripRenderEventArgs` Constructor and call `base.OnRenderImageMargin(newArgs);` with the new object (last comment, I promise :).

Comment: @jimi Calling `base.OnRenderImageMargin(newArgs);` doesn't increase the width of the image margin, but draws over the text portion. You are conflating rendering and layout.

Comment: Nope. I'm ignoring default Layout and rendering stuff where I want it to be using my measures. As mentioned (and described and shown in the post I linked), you can also move the Text of the same measure. That's why you handle a custom `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`.