# ContextMenuStrip icon transparency

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I changed the BackColor property of my ContextMenuStrip to something other than white, but the area on the left where the icons go is still white.
Is there a way to change the white color?

My icons are PNGs with transparency. The background color where the text is did get replaced, but the one where the icons are did not. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: [ProfessionalColorTable.ImageMarginGradientBegin](https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable.imagemargingradientbegin) etc. -- Sample code here: [Change space between Image and Text in ContextMenuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130479/7444103) -- Full code, but using VB.Net, unfortunately. Can be easily adapted to C# anyway.

Comment: @ThomasWeller my icons are PNGs with transparency. They do contain the white color (my ContextMenuStrip background color is black, and the icon elements are colored white). The background color where the text is did get replaced, but the one where the icons are did not. Here is how it looks like: https://i.imgur.com/L3Jz9fV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is not white. It starts at #FCFCFC on the left and goes to #F1F1F1 on the right. This is the "Professional" render mode.

If you change the render mode to "System" instead, it will be black as well:

```cs
contextMenuStrip1.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.System;
```

As long as the icon is transparent, the background will be black:

[image: Example]