# How to recolor back color and forecolor in VB.NET buttons that are found in dropdowns

Tags: vb.net

I am using status strips in VB.NET and I have a dropdown button where I place a few buttons such as new file and on these buttons I set the back color to black and forecolor to white on the status strip,dropdown and button but for the button, the colors only show as default. So I went from a code angle and used:
`statusStrip.backcolor = Color.Black`
`statusStrip.forecolor = Color.White`
`Drop.backcolor = Color.Black`
`Drop.forecolor = Color.White`
`btn.backcolor = Color.Black`
`btn.forecolor = Color.White`

In this model status strip is the strip, drop is dropdown button and btn is the button clicked.
The results show:

StatusStrip and it's buttons:

background: black

foreground: white

Dropdown button:

background: black

foreground: white

Dropdown contents and btn:

background: white

foreground: black

Comment: Build a ToolStripDropDown yourself (don't use the Form Designer), configure it and set it as the ToolStripDropDownButton's `DropDown`. The result is relatively poor. If you want to actually *design* it, then apply the custom Renderer shown here: [Change space between Image and Text in ContextMenuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130479/7444103) (it's a copy/paste thing: just get the classes and initialize the ToolStripDropDown object you created with `toolStripDesigner = New MenuDesigner([Your ToolStripDropDown]))` -- Assumed WinForms.

Comment: As shown in the examples, you can also use a ContextMenuStrip and use its Designer to simplify the process. A ContextMenuStrip is a ToolStripDropDown, where the DropDown  is not auto-generated (the `IsAutoGenerated` read-only Property is not set to `true` internally).